# Why is my compile time in Eclipse so long on an older iMac?

Tags: imac, eclipse

I have an iMac 27" from mid 2010 with 2,8 GHz Intel Core i5 CPU and 10GB RAM. It is running macOS High Sierra and things are okay on it except the browser gets a bit laggy when opening too much tabs.

I know this is an old setup for developing code but still I have this in my room and want to use it with Eclipse 4.13.

This works fine except for compiling even small pieces of code like the one below. Compiling it takes about 10 seconds each time.

I was wondering if there is some setting that I miss. I know that first compilations make take time, but then the following ones should go faster.

```
public class Klient {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Subjekt subject = new Stellvertreter();
    subject.operation();

}

}



abstract class Subjekt {

    public abstract void operation();

}


class RealesSubjekt extends Subjekt {

    public void operation() {
        System.out.println("Hier wird jetzt erst ausgeführt");

    }
}


class Stellvertreter extends Subjekt {

    RealesSubjekt realesSubjekt = new RealesSubjekt();

    public void operation() {
        System.out.println("Stellvertreter delegiert...");
        realesSubjekt.operation();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this happens because you have an HD instead of an SDD.

Comment: I actually have a hybrid 4TB SHDD, which has a SSD like part as kind of cache and the rest is HDD. But I also suspect this SHDD to slow down the iMac, so you might point to the right thing.

Comment: Eclipse 4.13 needs java8 - did you installed that?

Comment: Are you saying it is generally slow (in which case check [enable parallel build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53811668/2953889) setting) or is your problem that it is recompiling even if nothing has changed (in which case check [Project -> Build automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20024242/2953889)) ?

Comment: Thanks! I had a look into those. I am using it with Java. I could not find those exact setting options, probably because of Java. But I also thought that it might have something to do with unnecessary builds. It is not generally slow, just upon recompiling. But as I am just doing extremely small and light files I think it rebuilds something that is unnecessary.

Comment: @Yoan I checked again. Under `Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines` I have installed: `adoptopenjdk-11-openj9.jdk`.